# Format JSON out of a Hashmap<String,Hashmap>

Tags: java, json, gson

My problem is I have a `Hashmap<String,HashMap>` to make a hierarchy of a file-system. The key is the name of a file or folder and the value hashmaps from the files deeper in the hierarchy.

```
Hashmap
├── Key : Name of the File (eg. root)
└── Value : Deeper Files
    ├── Hashmap File 1
    │    ├── Key : Name of the File
    │    └── Value : Deeper Files
    └── Hashmap File 2
         ├── ....
```

Now I try to make this map with the pretty format of Gson to a JSON:

```
      {
      "": {
        "src": {
          "main": {
            "java": {
              "tools": {
                "mockfile": {
                  "generator": {
                    "data": {
                      "RecordPart.java": {},
                      "RecordAll.java": {}
                    },
                    "AnalyzerTEST.java": {},
                    "AnalyzerSFTP.java": {}
                  }
 ...
```

But for my application I need this format:

```
    {
     "name": "",
     "children": [
      {
       "name": "src",
       "children": [
        {
         "name": "main",
         "children": [
            {
             "name": "tools",
             "children": [
                {
                 "name": "generator",
                 "children": [
                    {
                     "name": "data",
                     "children": [
                        {"name": "RecordTotal.java"},
                        {"name": "RecordAll.java"}
                     ]
                    },
                    {"name": "AnalyzerTEST.java"},
                    {"name": "AnalyzerSFTP.java"}
                 ]
                }
 ...
```

Is there a way to solve this with my `Hashmap<String,Hashmap>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say we have the DTO

```
public class Data {
    private String name;
    private Data[] children;

    public Data(String name, Data[] children) {
        this.name = name;
        this.children = children;
    }
}
```

You need to convert your `HashMap<String, HashMap>` to DTO `Data` array.

```
private static Data[] convertMap2Data(HashMap<String, HashMap> map) {
    Data[] data = new Data[map.size()];
    int index = 0;
    for (Map.Entry<String, HashMap> entry : map.entrySet()) {
        data[index++] = new Data(entry.getKey(), convertMap2Data(entry.getValue()));
    }
    return data;
}
```

Here is how we use this method :

```
HashMap<String, HashMap> map = // You already have that
Data[] data = convertMap2Data(map);

Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();
System.out.println(gson.toJson(data[0])); // If there is only one root use this
//System.out.println(gson.toJson(data));  // If there are multiple root
```